# Looping through fread statements

Tags: c, loops, struct, eof, fread

Need to loop through the fread statements and print each one. However feof is printing an extra line at the end

The code works (as in is getting the right output) just need to not have that extra line

a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a

a

```
struct item input;

 FILE *fptr;
 fptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if(!fptr){
  FILE *fpOut = fopen(argv[1], "w");
 int c;
}

 if(fptr == NULL){
  fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
  exit(1);

 fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
while(!feof(fptr)){


 fread(&input.business, sizeof(float), 1, fptr);
 fread(&input.jellyfish, sizeof(char), 1, fptr);
 fread(&input.death, sizeof(input.death), 1, fptr);
 fread(&input.love, sizeof(input.love),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.ornament, sizeof(input.ornament), 1, fptr);
 fread(&input.taste, sizeof(input.taste),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.cloth, sizeof(input.cloth),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.name, sizeof(input.name),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.camera, sizeof(input.camera),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.attraction, sizeof(input.attraction),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.bottle, sizeof(input.bottle),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.stage, sizeof(input.stage),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.square, sizeof(input.square),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.bushes, sizeof(input.bushes),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.heat, sizeof(input.heat),1,fptr);
 fread(&input.fly, sizeof(input.fly),1,fptr);
 printf("%f ", input.business);
 printf("%c ", input.jellyfish);
 printf("%d ", input.death);
 printf("%c, ", input.love);
 printf("%d, ", input.ornament);
 printf("%f, ", input.taste);
 printf("%ld, ", input.cloth);
 printf("%d, ", input.name);
 printf("%d, ", input.camera);
 printf("%d, ", input.attraction);
 printf("%d, ", input.bottle);
 printf("%u, ", input.stage);
 printf("%f, ", input.square);
 printf("%d, ", input.bushes);
 printf("%s, ", input.heat);`
 printf("%d \n", input.fly);
```

Comment: I read that - however, I could not implement those methods into mine in a way that would work - that is with the use of structs

Comment: You should take some time and create a [mre]

Comment: `feof` does not tell whether a next read can be made. It tells whether the previous read encountered EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check of `eof()` occurs after `fread`.

```
while(!feof(fptr)){
    fread(&input.business, sizeof(float), 1, fptr);
    //...
    printf("%f ", input.business);
    //... 
}
```

So a call of `fread` can end unsuccessfully and the previous value of the corresponding argument will be outputted by a call of `printf`.

From the C Standard (7.21.8.1 The fread function)

> 3 The fread function returns the number of elements successfully read,
>   which may be less than nmemb if a read error or end-of-file is
>   encountered. If size or nmemb is zero, fread returns zero and the
>   contents of the array and the state of the stream remain unchanged

I can suggest the following approach to your task.

```
enum { N = 16 }; // number of fread calls
size_t n = 0, prev_n = 0;

do
{
    switch ( n )
    {
    case 0:
        n += fread( &input.business, sizeof(float), 1, fptr );
        break;
    case 1:     
        n += fread(&input.jellyfish, sizeof(char), 1, fptr );
        break;
    case 2:
        n += fread(&input.death, sizeof(input.death), 1, fptr );
        break;
    // ...
    }
} while ( prev_n != n && ( prev_n = n ) < N );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    switch ( i )
    {
    case 0:         
        printf("%f ", input.business);
        break;
    case 1:         
        printf("%c ", input.jellyfish);
        break;
    case 2:         
        printf("%d ", input.death);
        break;
    //...           
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the approach in action.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    int a[N];
    size_t n = 0, prev_n = 0;

    do
    {
        switch ( n )
        {
        case 0:
            n += scanf( "%d", a + n );
            break;
        case 1:     
            n += scanf( "%d", a + n );
            break;
        case 2:
            n += scanf( "%d", a + n );
            break;
        }
        // ...
    } while ( prev_n != n && ( prev_n = n ) < N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        switch ( i )
        {
        case 0:         
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
            break;
        case 1:         
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
            break;
        case 2:         
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
            break;
        //...           
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

if the input is

```
1 2 3
```

then the output is also

```
1 2 3
```